# HTML checkbox - cross browser issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, checkbox

I have a input - checkbox nested in elements and it shows okay in FF and chrome, but appears differently in IE8/9. The below nested structure is required as it has lots of other elements in it as well, which I just removed for the sake of clarity.

http://jsfiddle.net/D47jL/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="fieldwrapper">
    <div class="field">
        <div id="acc">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </label>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fieldwrapper .field input,
{

    border: 1px solid #41403E;
}

.fieldwrapper .field input[type="checkbox"] 
{
    border: none;
}
#acc label input { border:0 none;}
```

The first 2 styles in css were written in the application long back and I can not modify it, as its used in a no. of places, I can only write new or modify the 3rd style. I would like the checkbox to appear in IE as it is in FF. I tried, but no luck, not sure, may be I am missing something very simple. So, would appreciate if someone can help on this.

IE9 screenshot of jsfiddle - 
[image]

FF screenshot of jsfiddle -
[image]

Comment: It looks like if you remove all your custom styles it starts to look the same http://jsfiddle.net/D47jL/2/

Comment: **There is no guaranteed way to ensure cross browser style of checkboxes or radio buttons** unless you use css/html alternatives.

Comment: @iambriansreed - Well , in my case the styles are very simple, there was a border before and to remove that , a style has been added, shouldnt affect much, I think

Comment: @YuriyGalanter - As I said, I can not remove the first 2 styles, hence I added the 3rd one of my own, to remove border. The first 2 were written long back in this huge application, which are also used in a lot of other places.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Your fiddle _does_ look the same in IE9 as it does in Firefox.

Comment: @MrLister - I just edited the post and added the screenshots of checkbox in both browsers. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Internet explorer 9/10/11 the checkboxes looks different from how they looks in Blink and Gecko browsers. There is no good way(that have good browser support) to style checkboxes but you can hide them and style another element to work as a checkbox.

Here is some examples using that "hack": [CSSDECK CSS Checkbox-styles](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles).

Comment: Thanks for the link. But in my case, I have to use the default one's only. And I am really surprised that it is just the single line of css i.e. playing with border, which is actually creating such difference.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't the CSS, in IE they show up like that?

Comment: No, it is just this css which is causing the issue. If you remove up all the css here, it will look the same as in FF.

Comment: Then I would say you could write a reset CSS class? Check out the UAS that IE uses for the checkbox and use its styles to overwrite the existing one.

Comment: Reset css doesnt work, its already there in my application. I tried using the UAS for IE ( from this site - http://www.iecss.com/), but that didnt solve as well.

Comment: Hmm..strange..in my case its defaulting to FF look, if I remove all the css. I tested in IE9/8.

Comment: I think that this look(the withe one) is default in IE 10+ because it should match the "Modern" design in Win8. This showing up in IE 9 is weird, are you using the IE-edge meta(as you should)?

Comment: No, its not IE-edge meta. Its just IE9 only and for that matter, its showing the same behavior on IE8 as well.

Comment: But the only OS that's using IE9 right now(if updating is enabled) is Windows Phone 7 and Vista. Both Win7/8 is using IE11, so how big is the problem? sounds like a bug for me now...

Comment: Well, I am using Win 7 enterprise and I upgraded my browser to IE9, it was IE8 before.