# How to fix appearance:none for input in internet explorer?

Tags: css, reactjs, internet-explorer

[image]Hi guys. Actually I am working on checkbox. I used appearance:none for styling of input. It working on other browser but Internet Explorer show it like this. I tried lot of solution but without success. Sorry for image but i have problem with screenshots on virtual box.

Comment: see this https://caniuse.com/#search=appearance. appearance property is not supported in internet explorer. It has very minimal support in other browsers also

Comment: If you want checkboxes that look the same across browsers, you have no choice but to draw your own, and keep the real ones hidden with `display:none`. See also [Checkboxes Mozilla Cross-Browser issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35993044/1016716), [cross browser custom checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39732253/1016716), [Cross browser CSS checkbox issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43720087/1016716), [HTML checkbox - cross browser issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20789083/1016716), [CSS3 custom checkbox - cross-browser differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22606776/1016716) etc.

Comment: Since the [appearance isn't supported in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance). can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then, add two pictures about the success and fail result, it is better for us to give an alternative workaround.

Answer (score 1):

`appearance` isn't supported in IE.

Check this [support table](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance).

If you want change style of this element you have to rewrite it by yourself or use something like [iCheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com/).